# SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet myServletName

Tags: java, web, spring-tool-suite

Using Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3, I added the following to my POM.XML of my Maven Web project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.MyCompany.sei</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyCompany-archetype-war</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It successfully download this dependency and showed this new dependency in the Project Explorer->Libraries->Maven Dependencies folder

However, now when I try to access one of the test jsp pages in my HelloWorld web app running on the following STS web server "Tomcat v7 Server at localhost," I get the following error with nothing else changed.:

```
Feb 16, 2015 12:25:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet fitTrackerServlet as unavailable
Feb 16, 2015 12:25:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet myServletName
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So I comment out the added dependency and try again and get the same error again.

Looking at the differences with the last working version that I checked into SVN, I see that the following files have changed:

```
.classpath
.project
```

When I compare the new versions to the old, they look identical, with the exception of having some shuffling of the buildCommand and classpathentry nodes.

I as green as the summer grass when it comes to Java development. I at a basic level know that the info in these files is used to list dependencies and where to find jar files but I am puzzled why the web site now returns an error when reverting back to the original code. I've seen some references to running "Maven->Update Project" but this doesn't work. I've also tried to revert to the old versions of the classpath and project file and still it does not work.

I'm sure that something is getting out of whack here. I even tried Sopring Tools-> Reset Internal Cache on the project with no luck.

**Update**

By request, here is my dependency tree. Thank you!

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building FitnessTracker Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ FitnessTracker ---
[INFO] com.cigna:FitnessTracker:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] \- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.792 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-16T13:58:30-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/149M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You might post a pastebin of "mvn dependency:tree" from your top-level project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to let M2E rebuild your Eclipse project configuration files.

1. Remove your project from Eclipse
2. delete the the `.classpath`, `.project` and `.settings/` files from the file system
3. Import the project as an Existing Maven Project

Generally I don't store the IDE specific settings in version control anymore and let M2E do it for me.  This reduces the problems when people are using different variants and versions of the Eclipse IDE (i.e. Rational, Spring, Oracle or plain Eclipse)

I use the following [.gitignore](https://github.com/trajano/app/blob/master/.gitignore) file for my old projects using IntelliJ and Eclipse on both the Mac and Windows platforms.

```
*.iml
.DS_Store
.checkstyle
.classpath
.fbExcludeFilterFile
.idea
.metadata
.pmd
.pmdruleset.xml
.project
.settings/
artifacts.jar
bin
derby.log
logs.zip
pom.xml.releaseBackup
release.properties
target/
thumbs.db
```

If you need keep coding standards as part of your project, I use the [m2e-codestyle-maven-plugin](http://site.trajano.net/m2e-codestyle-maven-plugin/).

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.trajano.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>m2e-codestyle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>configure</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <codeStyleBaseUrl>codestyle</codeStyleBaseUrl>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.trajano</groupId>
      <artifactId>coding-standards</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That didn't help though I suspect that you were still offering good practical advice. The really frustrating part is that my Hello World projects seem to break on similar DispatcherServlet errors and I don';t understand why. In the latest project, I saw that the difference was do to a classpath difference where org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency was somehow ommited. I rolled ing back the classpath file and the app started to run again. However, my 1st proj didn't help. However, I rebooted last night and it started working again...sigh.